# static link glibc & boost_python36 for python extension

Tags: c++, boost-python

I'm writting a extension for pyton3.6. My develop machine run gcc7.3, and production environment os is centos6. I use the following link option to static link glibc to avoid upgrade glibc2.12 to glibc2.14+.

```
-Wl,-Bdynamic -lpython3.6m -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_python36
```

But get error:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared module helloext.so
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/helloext.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'helloext.so' failed
make[2]: *** [helloext.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/helloext.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloext.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Anyone known? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be although libgcc is present it may not be in the paths known to [ldconfig](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/ldconfig/). Check this by doing

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
```

Does the output show that there is a link to libgcc corresponds to paths that you have listed above?

A work around for you may be to add the link to the relevant library to your compile command [e.g.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1750758)

```
... -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/
```

Another may be to create a symbolic link to the library yourself.

```
 ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so /usr/lib/gcc/libgcc_s.so
```

*You have not informed us about Linux you are using. Update 4.6 with the proper number in the command above.*

Comment: the first command return: libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1, I had tried the two way your said, but still failed with 'cannot find -lgcc_s', I'm using ubuntu18.04(gcc7.3).